# BeautifulSoup How to get href links from pseudo-element/Class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/icbi20/current for the titles of all articles. The `HTML` is divided into Volumes and Issues. Each Volume has an Issue that corresponds to a Month. So for Volume 36 there would be 12 Issues. In the current Volume (37) there are 4 Issues and I would like to parse through each Issue and get each Article's name.

[image]

To accomplish this and automate the search I need to fetch the `href` links for each Issue. Initially I chose the parent's `div` `id`: `id = 'tocList'`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

chronobiology = requests.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/icbi20/current")
chrono_coverpage = chronobiology.content

issues = SoupStrainer(id ='tocList')
issues_soup = BeautifulSoup(chrono_coverpage, 'html.parser', parse_only = issues)
for issue in issues_soup:
    print(issue)
```

This returns a bs4 object **BUT** only with `href` links from the Volume `div`. What's worse is that this `div` should encompass both Volume `div` and Issue `div`.

So, I decided trying to reduce my search space and make it more specific and chose the `div` containing the Issue `href` links (`class_='issues'`)
[image]

This time Jupiter will think for a bit but won't return ANYTHING. Just blank. Nothing. Zippo. **BUT** if I ask what type of "nothing" has been returned, jupiter informs it is a "`String`"??? I just don't know what to make of this.
[image]

So, firstly I had a question, why is it that the Issue `div` element does not respond to the parsing? 
When I try running `print(BeautifulSoup(chrono_coverpage, 'html.parser').prettify())` the same occurs, the Issue `div` does not appear (When `Inspect Element` on the `html` page it appears immediatly beneath the final Volume `span`):

[image]

So I suspect that it must be javascript oriented or something, not so much HTML oriented. Or maybe the `class = 'open'` has something to do with it.

Any clarifications would be kindly appreciated. Also, how would one parse through Javascripted links to get them?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've "***resolved***" the issue though I need to fill in some theoretical gaps:

Firstly this snippet holds the key to the beginning of solving the answer:

[image]

As can be seen, the `<div class = 'container'>` is immediatly followed by a `::before` pseudo-element and the Links I am interested in are contained inside a `div` immediatly beneath this pseudo-element. This last `div` is then finished with the `::after` pseudo-element.

Firstly I realized that my problem was that I needed to select a pseudo-element. I found this to be quite impossible with `BeutifulSoup`'s `soup.select()` since apparently `BeautifulSoup` uses `Soup Sieve` which "*aims to allow users to target  XML/HTML elements with CSS selectors. It implements many pseudo-classes [...].*"

The last part of the paragraph states:

"*Soup Sieve also will not match anything for **pseudo classes that are only relevant in a live, browser environment**, **but it will gracefully handle them if they've been implemented**;*"

So this got me thinking that I have no idea what "pseudo classes that are only relevant in a live browser environment" means. But then I said to myself, "but it also said that had they been implemented, BS4 should be able to parse them". And since I can definitely see the `div` elements containing my `href` links of interest using the `Inspect` tool, I though that I must be implemented.

The first part of that phrase got me thinking: "But do I need a live browser for this to work?"

So that brought me to `Selenium`'s web driver:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url_chronobiology = driver.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/icbi20/current")
chronobiology_content = driver.page_source
chronobiology_soup = BeautifulSoup(chronobiology_content)
chronobiology_soup.select('#tocList > div > div > div.yearContent > div.issues > div > div')
```

```
[Out]: []
```

Clearly this result made me sad because I thought I had understood what was going on. But then I though that if I 'clicked' one of the issues, from the previously opened browser that it would work (for some reason, to be honest I'm pretty sure desperation led me to that thought).

Well, **surprise** surprise. It worked: After clicking on the "Issue 4" and re running the `script`, I got what I was looking for:

[image]

**UNANSWERED QUESTIONS?**

**1** - Apparently these pseudo-elements only "*exist*" when clicked upon, because otherwise the code doesn't recognize they are there. Why?

**2** - What code must be run in order to make an initial click and activiate these pseudo-elements so the code can automatically open these links and parse the information I want? (title of articles)

**UPDATE**

Question 2 is answered using Selenium's ActionChain:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url_chronobiology = driver.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/icbi20/current")
chronobiology_content = driver.page_source
chronobiology_soup = BeautifulSoup(chronobiology_content)
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tocList"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div')).perform()

chronobiology_soup.select('#tocList > div > div > div.yearContent > div.issues > div > div')
```

```
[Out]: 
[<div class="loi-issues-scroller">
 <a class="open" href="/toc/icbi20/37/4?nav=tocList">Issue<span>4</span></a>
 <a class="" href="/toc/icbi20/37/3?nav=tocList">Issue<span>3</span></a>
 <a class="" href="/toc/icbi20/37/2?nav=tocList">Issue<span>2</span></a>
 <a class="" href="/toc/icbi20/37/1?nav=tocList">Issue<span>1</span></a>
 </div>]
```

**The only downside** is that one must stay on the page for `Selenium`'s `ActionChain.perform()` can actually click the element, **but** at least I've automated this step.

If someone could **answer question 1** that would be great